# Missing rows from ZF2 SQL statement and ResultSet

Tags: database, zend-framework2

Hit a brick wall with this now. I have a query, with some joins so running it through this (TableGateway will not play with fields from other tables):

```
$sql = new Sql($adapter);
$select = getMySelect();

echo $select->getSqlString($this->adapter->getPlatform());
//ok - this, if I run it on the database MYSELF, yields 2 of rows with the current data. Correct.

$statement = $this->adapter->query($select->getSqlString($this->adapter->getPlatform())); 

$res = $statement->execute();
$resultSet = new ResultSet;
$resultSet->initialize($res);

echo $resultSet->count(); // yields 2. Correct, but wait...

foreach($resultSet as $row)
{
   //do stuff with $row .... but only happens once! wtf.
}

print_r($resultSet->toArray()); //only one array element, with nested row data - wtf.
```

So, in short. The sql, run through MySQL manually, gives *two rows* (or more, if I add things into the db) . The Zend\Db\ResultSet *itself* reports that it has **two rows**. But it won't yield them both to a foreach loop.

I don't get it. Is there some ZendFrameworky2 magic dance I missed out? Just giving it one more chance before going back to trusty plain ol' PDO.

Answer (score 2):

I tracked the problem down to the tablegateway and the example code used by Zend for checking that there is a valid result set.

```
$row = $resultSet->current();
if (!$row) {
    throw new Exception("no row found");
}
return $resultSet;
```

which has already moved the pointer in the result set to index 1 by getting the current row, which then becomes the starting point for the foreach.

To fix, change to

```
$row = $resultSet->count();
if (!$row) {
    throw new Exception("no row found");
}
return $resultSet;
```